# Git: convert carriage return \r to new line \n with git hook?

Tags: git, githooks, newline

A fellow coder uses a Windows computer that is putting carriage returns everywhere in our source.

Is there a way to write a git hook that converts all `\r\n` to `\n`?

**Note** I haven't used git hooks before, so a little extra hand-holding might go a long way :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest thing is to [set `core.autocrlf` to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278) on The Windows side.
(that way Git won't do any conversion and will keep the eol untouched).

On the unix side, a `core.autocrlf` set to true could help restore the proper eol.
As [mathepic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205756/mathepic) mentions in the comments, and as [I described in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206843/how-line-ending-conversions-work-with-git-core-autocrlf-between-different-operati/3209806#3209806), since Git1.7.2, you can use **`core.eol`** (to native), keeping `core.autocrlf` to false.

Otherwise you can use a [text driver or a filter driver with `gitattributes` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows/2517442#2517442).
No hooks needed.

Comment: VonC, perhaps i want `core.autocrlf` set to true? I **want** to remove the carriage returns.

Comment: @macek: `autocrlf` might do the job on the Unix side, but I would recommend it to false on the Windows side, in order to not introduce all those crlf in the first place. I have edited my answer to reflect those choices and settings.

Comment: `core.eol` is the new way to do this, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If they're using TortoiseGit, there's an option to do this for you, under Git->Config->Auto CRLF convert.