# CMake compiler settings specific to the local working copy

Tags: cmake

Currently to change a compiler flag when using gcc, I edit the CMakeLists.txt for the build target:

```
if (UNIX)
    add_definitions(-Wall)
    add_definitions(-g)
    #add_definitions(-O2)
endif (UNIX)
```

The problem with this is that git picks up the change. If I go ahead and commit this change, I will annoy the other developers who expect to use -O2 instead of -g but they get my version when they pull unrelated changes. Normally, I could just exclude this change from my commits, but when I make an *actual* change to the CMakeLists.txt file, there is no way to avoid pushing up my personal selection of compile flags.

Is there a way to tell CMake to create a file in the build/ directory (specific to each working copy, and therefore to each developer) that an individual person can modify to their heart's desire without touching project files (everything but build/). Naturally, our build/ is not committed to the git repository.

It might be helpful to note that when using Visual Studio instead of gcc, the IDE handles this for us through its UI which modifies the VS solution file in build/. The problem is that we have no such mechanism when using GNU Makefiles.

Our project is organized like this:

```
ourproject/
    bin/
    build/ <-- CMake-generated stuff goes here
    lib/
    src/
        abuildtarget/
        anotherbuildtarget/
            source.cpp
            source.h
            CMakeLists.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using CMake incorrectly here. The `add_definitions` function is not for adding compiler options like you are doing; rather, it is to add pre-processor definitions such as `add_definitions(-DDEBUG)`.

What you want to do is set the `CMAKE_<language>_FLAGS` when you configure to the options you want. If there is a standard set you need, then put that in the CMakeLists.txt file such as:

```
if(${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "Intel")                                   
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2 -xhost" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_NODEBUG "-O0" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
  mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_NODEBUG)

  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_PROFILING "-O2 -xhost -p" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
  mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_PROFILING)

  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG
      "-DDEBUG -g -check noarg_temp_created -C -traceback" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
endif()
```

Where `Fortran` can be replaced by `CXX` or `C`.

In this case, the `CMAKE_<language>_FLAGS_<build type>` sets the flags based on the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable. If it is set to `Release`, then it uses `CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE`. We added several other possible build types. If the user wants something that isn't one of the standard build types, then they set `CMAKE_<language>_FLAGS` to whatever they want when configuring and it overrides the build type setting and uses the user-defined flags instead.

Comment: I think you shouldn't just `set` the flags - it will overwrite whatever has been put in there beforehands (for example by a user specifying `-DCMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS=...` on the command line). I would rather do `set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} new_stuff")`.

Comment: @Ela782 I think the best practice is to set the `CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_<build type>` flags like I do in my example because those are supposed to be set by the code and not the user. The user can always override any of those by setting the `CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS` either through the command line or through the `ccmake` interface. The problem with your option is when the user specifies something that conflicts with `new_stuff`. Some compilers may complain about conflicting options, some may just pick one and not tell you which they picked.

Comment: In general, the 'CMAKE_<language>_FLAGS` variable shouldn't be set by the developer in the CMake files; the developer should only set the build configurations and leave the generic option for the user to specify if something else is needed.

Comment: Ok, I see the difference now between the generic `CMake_<language>_FLAGS` and the ones with appended `_<build type>`! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

While there's almost certainly a better method of utilising `cmake` to solve your problem, this part of your question is easily addressed:

> but when I make an actual change to the CMakeLists.txt file, there is no way to avoid pushing up my personal selection of compile flags.

This is only true if you *commit* your specific, personal file changes to your local repository, and even then you can either `git-revert` when you make a patch to push, or use a filter between your `development` and `ready-to-push-to-other-developers` branches - the rough idea can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows/2517442#2517442), although you'll have to edit it pretty heavily to remove the offending personal lines from the questions example.

A better option, then, is to *not commit* the personal changes. From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/how-can-i-commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git), you can easily commit specific changes to a file.

A thing to note, however, is that you'll end up with a permanently dirty work-tree if you've got uncommitted changes to a non-ignored file; this may or may not be an issue, depending on your workflow for merges etc.