# How to change line-ending settings

Tags: git, msysgit

Is there a file or menu that will let me change the settings on how to deal with line endings?

I read there are 3 options:

1. **Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style**

   Git will convert LF to CRLF when checking out text files. When
   committing text files, CRLF will be converted to LF. For
   cross-platform projects, this is the recommended setting on Windows
   ("core.autocrlf" is set to "true")
2. **Checkout as-is, commit Unix-style**

   Git will not perform any conversion when checking out text files.
   When committing text files, CRLF will be converted to LF. For
   cross-platform projects this is the recommended setting on Unix
   ("core.autocrlf" is set to "input").
3. **Checkout as-is, commit as-is**

   Git will not perform any conversions when checking out or committing
   text files. Choosing this option is not recommended for cross-platform
   projects ("core.autocrlf" is set to "false")

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force git to use LF instead of CR+LF under windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows)

Comment: Which of these is the default?

Comment: @Stephen default is false, [check](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)

Comment: I actually find that the 3-rd option works better. Otherwise I often have been in situations when I edit both batch and sh scripts on the same platform (Windows/Linux) and then commit them and Git automatically "fixes" line endings for one platform... No, I prefer to be self-conscious about line endings and commit/checkout them exactly as they are.

Comment: Agree with @JustAMartin having the system messing with your line endings is a great way to introduce bugs that will take an entire day to track down and fix, as I just have. All decent editors and IDEs on Windows now fully support LF line endings nowadays, there is no need for this translation.

Comment: @Neutrino I wish this was true, but one example of IDE that messes with your line endings (and doesn't offer a reasonable configuration option to turn this off) is Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio has supported [.editorconfig](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/editorconfig-reference-for-c-developers#end_of_line) files for ages. This is a really good way to configure text settings across all file types in a solution and is supported by all good editors.

Comment: Agree with @JustAMartin. The default is especially bad if you use Docker for Windows. You'll end up copying CRLF files into a Docker image and get cryptic errors from the Linux util programs that try to process them.

Comment: @Aurast, in such a case, why not `input`? This always checkout files as they are in checked-in to **git**, `LF` for files that are `eol` converted. Pro tip, you can check the status of `eol` for all files tracked by **git** using `git ls-files --eol`. The first column `i/` is for the **index**, the stuff checked-id, `w/` is for the working tree, the stuff checked out

Comment: note that changing to `input`, doesn't change line-ending until that file is checked out again. So you have to checkout all files for this to take effect. The easiest way probably checking out the first commit, then back to HEAD of the curent branch `git rev-list HEAD | tail -1 | xargs git checkout && git switch -`

Comment: My personal experience is that `autoclrf false` creates a complete mess when used on Windows. Some files `CLRF` some `LF`. `autoclrf true` is a must if you're running two **VCS** or something else that is sensitive to line-ending changes. Most sensible Windows editors have no problem opening `LF` files. If they for some reason misbehave and revert to CLRF, no biggie, it get checked in as `LF` with `input`

Comment: I use `wsl` and have a system wide config `C:/git/etc/gitconfig` for both Linux and Windows. Can I set the `autocrlf` there or should I do two different settings in the `home` configs as Jasnan does with `input` and `true`?

Comment: Just now I spent one hour trying to figure why my SH script was not running, This option should be completely removed. In 21st century, all good programming editors work with unix eof.

Comment: @CervEd Because the checkout is not performed in the Docker container, but in Windows.

Comment: @Sandburg sorry, you're going to have to elaborate what you're referring to. If you checkout in windows, the line-endings in your working directory will depend the settings of `core.eol` and `core.autocrlf`. Also note that `core.autocrlf` overrides `core.eol` if it's set to `true` or `input`

Answer (score 782, accepted):

The normal way to control this is with `git config`

For example

```sh
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

For details, scroll down in [this link to Pro Git](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_formatting_and_whitespace) to the section named "core.autocrlf"

---

If you want to know what *file* this is saved in, you can run the command:

```sh
git config --global --edit
```

and the git global config file should open in a text editor, and you can see where that file was loaded from.

Comment: `input` is the 3rd option (as stated in the link I provided). The 3 options are `true` | `false` | `input`

Comment: Here is another good SO question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206843/how-line-ending-conversions-work-with-git-core-autocrlf-between-different-operat

Comment: Actually, if you re-read your own question, in the copy/pasted excerpts : `"1 ... ("core.autocrlf" is set to "true") ... 2 ... ("core.autocrlf" is set to "input") ... 3 ... ("core.autocrlf" is set to "false")"` so you basically answered your own question? :)

Comment: Pro git has been absorbed by git-scm. An equivalent link to the git-scm book is the [formatting and whitespace configuration section](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace).

Comment: You might want to use `--system` rather than `--global` in some settings.

Comment: This is the old way to go around it. Look at .gitattributes file.

Comment: this is especially visible where windows does not register any change, default endings in linux would change all the files, so it  is useful to have the endings on both systems same either crlf, or only lf

Comment: it should be noted that after changing this setting, it helps to `git rm --cached -r .` and then `git reset --hard` in order to rewrite all files in the working tree. You will lose uncommitted changes by doing this!

Comment: I use `windows` and `linux` for my git repos, and `vscode` with always `lf` on both. I have `core.autocrlf` to `false` and it works, always using `lf`.

Answer (score 294):

Line ending format used in OS:

- Windows: `CR` (Carriage Return `\r`) and `LF` (LineFeed `\n`) pair
- OSX, Linux: `LF` (LineFeed `\n`)

We can configure git to auto-correct line ending formats for each OS in two ways.

1. Git Global configuration
2. Using `.gitattributes` file

### Global Configuration

#### In Linux/OSX

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

This will fix any `CRLF` to `LF` when you commit.

#### In Windows

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

This will make sure that, when you checkout in windows, all `LF` will be converted to `CRLF`.

### .gitattributes File

It is a good idea to keep a `.gitattributes` file as we don't want to expect everyone in our team to set their own config. This file should be placed in the repository root and, if it exists, git will respect it.

```
* text=auto
```

This will treat all files as text files and convert to OS's line ending on checkout and back to `LF` on commit automatically. If you want to specify the line ending explicitly, you can use:

```
* text eol=crlf
* text eol=lf
```

The first one is for checkout and the second one is for commit.

```
*.jpg binary
```

This will treat all `.jpg` images as binary files, regardless of path. So no conversion needed.

Or you can add path qualifiers:

```
my_path/**/*.jpg binary
```

Comment: What about OS X, which uses `CR` (carriage return) alone?

Comment: Legacy MacOS (that is, MacOS 9 and earlier) used `CR` alone, but OS X generally uses `LF`.

Comment: Can I use `* text eol=lf` twice to have it checkout with `LF` on Windows?

Comment: According to [gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#Documentation/gitattributes.txt-Settostringvalueauto) setting `* text=auto` lets git decide whether the content is text or not. Forcing all files to be text should be `* text` only.

Comment: Which of those are off - leave my files alone - my files my line endings - don't change anything?

Comment: `The first one is for checkout and the second one is for commit.` Are you sure? I see no documentation supporting this

Answer (score 39):

> For a repository setting solution, that can be redistributed to all developers, check out the [text](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) attribute in the [.gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file. This way, developers dont have to manually set their own line endings on the repository, and because different repositories can have different line ending styles, global core.autocrlf is not the best, at least in my opinion.

For example unsetting this attribute on a given path [*.* - text] will force git not to touch line endings when checking in and checking out. In my opinion, this is the best behavior, as most modern text editors can handle both type of line endings. Also, if you as a developer still want to do line ending conversion when checking in, you can still set the path to match certain files or set the eol attribute (in .gitattributes) on your repository.

Also check out this related post, which describes .gitattributes file and text attribute in more detail: [What's the best CRLF (carriage return, line feed) handling strategy with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-carriage-return-line-feed-handling-strategy-with-git)

Comment: `. - text` gives `is not a valid attribute name: .gitattributes:1` please put `cat .gitattributes`

Answer (score 20):

### The .gitattributes file

The easiest way is to use a local `.gitattributes` file in your repo.

You can also change line-endings for specific file extensions too

```sh
*           text=auto     # auto
*.txt       text
*.vcproj    text eol=crlf # windows line-endings
*.sh        text eol=lf   # linux line-endings
*.jpg       -text
```

This also overrides the global defaults, so it's much more portable and makes the repo more reliable on different machines.

Comment: You have to remove comments at the end of lines to prevent `# is not a valid attribute name: .gitattributes:1` errors during the checkout

Comment: If you want to do it for files in a particular subfolder: `path/to/subfolder/*.sh`. Recursively: `path/to/subfolder/**/*.sh`.

Answer (score 16):

For me what did the trick was running the command

```
git config auto.crlf false
```

inside the folder of the project, I wanted it specifically for one project.

That command changed the file in path {project_name}/.git/config (fyi .git is a hidden folder) by adding the lines

```
[auto]
    crlf = false
```

at the end of the file. I suppose changing the file does the same trick as well.

Comment: Thank you! I tried `core.autocrlf=false` which did not work for me in WSL, while GitBash 
 and IntelliJ had no problem with that.

Comment: The correct answer and it should be set globally. This is one of the dumbest design decisions in anything ever. Line ending changes are not guaranteed to be lossless and this is just a time waster.

Answer (score 8):

### For the option "checkout as is, commit as is" in Windows:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

This will not modify line endings at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert back the file formats which have been changed to UNIX Format from PC format.

(1)You need to reinstall tortoise GIT and in the "Line Ending Conversion" Section make sure that you have selected "Check out as is - Check in as is"option.

(2)and keep the remaining configurations as it is.

(3)once installation is done

(4)write all the file extensions which are converted to UNIX format into a text file (extensions.txt).

```
ex:*.dsp
   *.dsw
```

(5) copy the file into your clone
Run the following command in GITBASH

```
while read -r a;
do
find . -type f -name "$a" -exec dos2unix {} \;
done<extension.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Below steps work for me

Add a git attributes on root project folder (it will be useful for upcoming file)

```
* text=auto

*.tf  eol=lf
*.tfvars  eol=lf
*.yml  eol=lf
```

After execute below command for give a support to already exist files

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.tf -o -iname \*.tfvars -o -iname \*.md -o -iname \*.yml \) -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix

dos2unix .gitignore
dos2unix .gitattributes
```