# Using tr to replace newline with space

Tags: replace, newline, space, git-bash, tr

Have output from `sed`:

```
http://sitename.com/galleries/83450
72-profile
```

Those two strings should be merged into one and separated with space like:

```
http://sitename.com/galleries/83450 72-profile
```

Two strings are pipelined to `tr` in order to replace newline with space:

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

And it's not working, the result is the same as input.

Indicating space with ASCII code `'\032'` results in replacing `\n` with non-printable characters.

What's wrong? I'm using Git Bash on Windows.

Comment: I tested piping a text file with newlines to tr with the same syntax and it works.  How are you doing the pipe? Does the file have newlines AND linefeeds? maybe try "tr '\r\n' ' '"

Comment: Why is this marked as a duplicate? The linked question specifically asked _using **sed**_, which is not what this question is about (_using **tr**_). Though the goal is the same, there may be a lot of reasons why the asker or a viewer would like to use tr and tr only.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Best guess is you are on windows and your line ending settings are set for windows. 
See this topic: [How to change line-ending settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings)

or use:

```
tr '\r\n' ' '
```

Comment: agree about windows line endings. The quick fix is `dos2unix file`. Good luck to all.

Comment: well the script still has '\r'. But it doesn't look like it will work for what you want. It will put everything on one line, not just 2 lines at a time, and then your FOR loop will always go through just once.