# Edmx generate model file with blank lines

Tags: edmx

How can I configure the code Generation in VisualStudio 2015 using Database first to not generate extra blank lines in my model?

multiple people are working on this project and the source control system really don't like it :(

Maybe the solution could be to configure GIT to ignore white space?
[see what the merge tool show me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Ug9.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be because of T4 file generator. Open with Notepad++ your emdx .tt file, **go to Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Windows (CR LF)**.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42442170/3390216) answer.

Comment: A slightly more robust solution is to also tell git to always use CRLF for those .tt files; adding a line to the `.gitattributes` file like `*.tt eol=crlf` may help.