# Can't cancel my update

Tags: git, git-stash, git-checkout

I have a question about git command.
I tried to cancel my update from git stash.
But i wasn't able to do it.

I use the following command.

```
    ~/xxxxx-repo on  master! ⌚ 18:27:45
$ git checkout . 
                                                                                                                                                   ~/xxxxx-repo on  master! ⌚ 18:28:02
$ git status                                                                                                                                                                                       2.3.1
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 3 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   app/Api/Middleware/ViewSwitchMiddleware.php
    modified:   app/Common/Data/Api/Lib/ParamWithPaginator.php
    modified:   app/Common/Data/DB/Sample.php
    modified:   app/Common/Data/DB/User.php
    modified:   app/Framework/Data/CurlBasicManager.php
    modified:   app/Framework/Lib/ArrayObject.php
    modified:   app/Tool/Middleware/ViewSwitchMiddleware.php
    modified:   config/data.php
    modified:   nbproject/project.properties
    modified:   nbproject/project.xml
    modified:   public/vendor/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.css
    modified:   public/vendor/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.js
    modified:   public/vendor/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

~/xxxxx-repo on  master! ⌚ 18:28:05
$ git pull origin master                                                                                                                                                                           2.3.1
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote:
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
From ssh://xxxxxxx.xxxx.com/v1/repos/xxxxxx-repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   3803c7a..850eb4c  master     -> origin/master
Updating ee9814f..850eb4c
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/Framework/Data/CurlBasicManager.php
    config/data.php
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Why didn't i cancel my update?

I'm struggling this error today.

I tried to delete this repository.

Then i clone the same repository.

Then i tried the following command.

But the same error reproduced even if I have not updated any file yet.

And I tried the following way.
But I still was not able to solve my problem.

```
      ~/XXXXXXx-repo on  master! ⌚ 20:35:30
  $ git add app/Framework/Data/CurlBasicManager.php                                                                                                                                                  2.3.1
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Framework/Data/CurlBasicManager.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

  ~/XXXXXX-repo on  master! ⌚ 10:24:08
  $ git add config/data.php                                                                                                                                                                          2.3.1
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in config/data.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

  ~/XXXXX-repo on  master! ⌚ 10:24:29
  $ git stash                                                                                                                                                                                        2.3.1
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in .gitignore.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Api/Middleware/ViewSwitchMiddleware.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Common/Data/Api/Lib/ParamWithPaginator.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Common/Data/DB/Sample.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Common/Data/DB/User.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Framework/Lib/ArrayObject.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Tool/Middleware/ViewSwitchMiddleware.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in nbproject/project.properties.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in nbproject/project.xml.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in public/vendor/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.css.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in public/vendor/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.js.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in public/vendor/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in .gitignore.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Api/Middleware/ViewSwitchMiddleware.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Common/Data/Api/Lib/ParamWithPaginator.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Common/Data/DB/Sample.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Common/Data/DB/User.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Framework/Lib/ArrayObject.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/Tool/Middleware/ViewSwitchMiddleware.php.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in nbproject/project.properties.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in nbproject/project.xml.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in public/vendor/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.css.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in public/vendor/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.js.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in public/vendor/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js.
  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
  Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: ee9814f refs #4 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  HEAD is now at ee9814f refs #4 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

  ~/XXXXX-repo on  master! ⌚ 10:24:36
  $ git pull                                                                                                                                                                                         2.3.1
  remote: Counting objects: 47, done.
  remote:
  Unpacking objects: 100% (47/47), done.
  From ssh://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/v1/repos/CandY-repo
     850eb4c..2410322  master     -> origin/master
  Updating ee9814f..2410322
  error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/Framework/Data/CurlBasicManager.php
    config/data.php
  Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
  Aborting
```

I'm still struggling...

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: After the above you did `git stash` and then tried `git pull` again and got the same result? What does `git status` show you after the stash?

Comment: @lvan  
I use mac OS X

Comment: @bcmcfc I got same error,same status.

Comment: That's a very different error! The line endings can be configured

Comment: @bcmcfc I'm so sorry.

Comment: It's a significant amount of detail to omit. Plus it's very easily searchable! Nearly always the output from git will tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why didn't i cancel my update?

`git checkout .` gets files from the index and restore them to the working directory.
Your modifications were already staged (i.e. in the index), so you needed to `git checkout HEAD .` to discard them.

Regarding the problem, you set core.autocrlf to true, right?
It's a config to be used when you're on Windows and working on a repo made in Unix. So it's not for you.
This config converts CRLF to LF when add, which is probably the cause of the issue.
You can set core.autocrlf to false by:

```
git config --local core.autocrlf false
```

Also run it with `--global` instead of `--local` if you want the config globally.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a couple of issues now that the question is updated.

Different OSs use different line endings.

Git can be configured to leave them alone so it doesn't try to change them every time. More on that in this question and answer: [How to change line-ending settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10418975/149998)

The other issue is potentially that the files in question are untracked and therefore aren't being stashed for that reason.

```
git add app/Framework/Data/CurlBasicManager.php
git add config/data.php
```

Then

```
git stash
```

Then you will be able to `git pull`.

The output from git status will always explain what's going on.

Comment: Unfortunately,the same error happened.I will update my question.

Comment: my coworker uses windows,however i use mac.probably it might be reason.

Comment: You should've included all that error output in your original question. Was it really not present?