# Getting "exec user process caused "no such file or directory"" error when trying to run Docker image

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I'm trying to run a simple image that executes .sh file but I got this error.

> standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2
ADD . .
CMD ["./test.sh"]
```

`test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test"
```

I'm running Docker in Windows 10 and I have checked '/bin/bash' is existed in the container.

Why I got this error?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the exact same issue when I tried to create a Linux container image with Docker on windows 10. When you copy the file from windows to docker image, the file format is that of dos. You may need to run **dos2unix** utility on all the files before copying them inside docker image.

To make things clear, I would share my experience. When I checked out my project source code using git on windows and tried to create a linux docker container by building the image locally, I got the exact same error message. This happened because I created my git project on Linux but this time, I checked out on windows. My default git global configuration on windows was checkout Windows-style commit Unix-style, i.e. Git will convert LF to CRLF when checking out text files. When committing text files, CRLF will be converted to LF. For cross-platform projects, this is the recommended setting on Windows ("core.autocrlf" is set to "true")

In order to resolve this, I changed my windows' git global config as I wanted to checkout Unix-style commit Unix-style.([How to change line-ending settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings))

```
git config --global autocrlf input
```

After this, I checked out my project again and created a fresh local image that ran perfectly.

Comment: It is a very valid answer. Another way to quickly fix the problem in a particular file is: open it in Notepad++ and click menu Edit/EOL Conversions/Unix