# white space added on one line and removed on the next line in the same git commit

Tags: ide, bitbucket, rubymine

This is a really annoying random issue. What cause this? Is there a way I can prevent it?

[image: Photo From Bitbucket]

I see that Bitbucket has an ignore whitespace option but it seems like that just encourages a sloppy whitespace free-for-all on a team.

Comment: hmmm could be caused by different end of file settings (newline or not settings). if this is the case this is potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are actually spaces being saved there which is evident from the different green shade.