# Why is Git changing the size of my text files when cloning?

Tags: git

When I got [here](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language/blob/lstm_compiler_benchmark/Temporary/tiny_shakespeare.txt) and get this file by hand it comes out to 1.06mb. When I clone the whole branch that files becomes 1.1Mb. Why is this happening? Renaming the `txt` postfix into something else like `data` does not work either.

The test requires the file to have its size statically asserted and it suddenly changing is making it throw an exception.

`git clone -b lstm_compiler_benchmark --single-branch https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language/` can be used if you want to quickly check it out.

Comment: How are you working out the file size?

Comment: In the online repo you can see it says 1.06Mb. When you download it by hand and check the size by right clicking and Properties it also says 1.06Mb. The size assert in the test also passes. When it is cloned, it comes out to 1.1Mb and the assert fails. This is on Windows.

Comment: And when you do a diff of expected vs actual; what's the difference?  Money says that you're committing with unix style line endings; and checking out with windows style

Comment: Well, the IDE shows nothing on the change tab. You are probably right about this. How do I stop this from happening? I remember turning on the option to normalize by default, and am not sure how to disable it now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed `text=auto` to `text=input` in the `.gitattributes` file and now it works properly.