# clean git clone has wrong line endings

Tags: git, newline

I got some cruel problem. Since some weeks ago, git clones don't work correctly on our PCs in about 20% of the cases..
Directly after cloning, git status tells me differences in random files. Dumping that clone and cloning again, other files are "different"

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   marvin-jee/marvin-ejb/src/main/dd/release/META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml
        modified:   marvin-jee/marvin-ejb/src/main/java/xxx/yyy/zzz.java
        modified:   marvin-jee/marvin-ejb/src/main/java/xxx/yyy/zsss.java
    ... some random files...
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

removing that clone and cloning again may result in other files or no error..

i just tried under linux and get "changes" in random files where $Log $ and $Id$ are processed.. But CRLF is no problem there.

I suppose that there's some problem with processing .gitattributes.
maybe in correlation with Eclipse IDE we also use? (jgit, which doesn't process .gitattributes?)

Comment: Could you run `git fsck` on your server side repo?

Comment: shure, here it is:

`[git@V0001230 21]$ git fsck --no-dangling
Prüfe Objekt-Verzeichnisse: 100% (256/256), Fertig.
Prüfe Objekte: 100% (976/976), Fertig.`
does not look like having errors

Comment: What is the actual diff that you see? Is it just the line endings that become different? What are the line ending settings you have? ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings )

Comment: autocrlf is true, line endings for .xml and .java is set to `text eol=lf ident`