# docker-compose up: utf-8 codec can't decode byte X

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

Everytime I run docker-compose up on my machine (macOS 10.13.5, latest docker version) I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "docker-compose", line 6, in
>      File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main   File
>   "compose/cli/main.py", line 124, in perform_command   File
>   "compose/cli/command.py", line 41, in project_from_options   File
>   "compose/cli/command.py", line 126, in get_project   File
>   "compose/project.py", line 96, in from_config   File
>   "compose/network.py", line 320, in get_networks   File
>   "compose/network.py", line 125, in true_name   File
>   "compose/network.py", line 146, in _set_legacy_flag   File
>   "compose/network.py", line 106, in inspect   File
>   "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped   File
>   "site-packages/docker/api/network.py", line 211, in inspect_network
>   File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
>   File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 194, in _get   File
>   "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get   File
>   "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in request   File
>   "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 424, in prepare_request
>   File "site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 195, in get_netrc_auth
>   File "netrc.py", line 33, in **init**   File "netrc.py", line 42, in
>   _parse   File "shlex.py", line 105, in get_token   File "shlex.py", line 136, in read_token   File
>   "/Users/distiller/compose-osx-release/compose/venv/lib/python3.6/codecs.py",
>   line 321, in decode UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode
>   byte 0x80 in position 33: invalid start byte

Comment: My first instinct is that this error means what it says: you somehow have the byte 0x80 in some file in your system (maybe not the `docker-compose.yml`) and it’s not UTF-8-encoded text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so apparently there is a problem with the current version of docker-compose for macOS... It's just my guess, but anyhow here is how I solved it

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.14.0-rc2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Then restarted the terminal

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and this may also be related to your `.env` files.

Ensure that your .env files are UTF-8.

```sh
sudo apt install moreutils
isutf8 yourfile.env
```

If `isutf8` returns no output it's likely a valid UTF-8 file.

Additionally, check the *contents* of the .env file you're referencing in your docker-compose.yml.  Any incorrectly decrypted secrets/values you may be using locally can cause this problem too.

If in doubt, clear the env file and readd lines until you hit the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ideas:
1. try to reinstall your python
2. use not the latest docker version, but the latest stable

Comment: i will try to re install python2, docker is already the latest stable version

Comment: The issue is about python3.6 here:  "/Users/distiller/compose-osx-release/compose/venv/lib/python3.6/codecs.py"

Comment: I re installed python2 just to be sure. But in anycase I knew its not the issue, since I do not have python3 on my machine. Looks like docker has its own python enviroment .. distiller is not a user i have on my machine

Comment: @EbramSherif Check your git settings. Maybe you have windows line endings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was creating an empty .env file in the directory I run docker-compose in (encoded as UTF-8).

Comment: If it's empty, it doesn't *have* an encoding.

Comment: @tripleee Sounds reasonable, yes. Notepad++ shows UTF-8 as the encoding anyway. So I wanted to add this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to the pycharm env file, double click it and install the python env file. Then run the code [docker-compose up airflow-init] again, it'll work.