# Change the line endings in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2017, line-endings

How do I change the line endings of all source files in an existing project in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac?

I have cloned a Git project where a few of the files have mixed line endings. The vast majority of the source files use Unix line endings (`\n`). I used a regex search and replace to find all `\u2028` (LINE SEPARATOR) characters and replace them with `\n`, but I'm wondering if there's a way to normalise the line endings in a simpler way.

The problem these supported but non-standard line endings have is that Git doesn't recognise them, causing multiple lines to be marked as changed, when only a single line has really been changed.

I have seen some line ending answers for the Windows version of Visual Studio 2017, but the Mac version is quite different, so the answers weren't applicable.

Comment: This answer on how to control line endings for Git might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821931/3735425

Comment: @ColleenV As far as I can tell, Git only recognises `\r` and `\n` as newline characters.

Answer (score 6):

You can change how you save individual files in Visual Studio for Mac

1. Go to Visual Studio > Preferences
2. In the dialog box that appears scroll the left menu down to the Text Editor section and select General.
3. In the first option, **Line ending conversion**, change `Leave line endings as is` to `Always convert line endings`.

[image: screenshot of dialog]

Comment: Presumably there's no difference from accessing this setting via Preferences in the app menu?