# Docker 409 Client error. How to get real error and see the real log in container?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I am struggling with docker and akka.net

I am always getting this error but I do not know how to check what throws this error? Is it possible to check logoutput of the container or somehow see the output?

Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 246, in _raise_for_status
  File "site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 409 Client Error: Conflict for url: http+docker://localnpipe/v1.30/containers/4d9d4008ccc0abacbee66357ff73e351df9997d7ec0cda8d0e0a696edf489eed/attach?logs=0&stdout=1&stderr=1&stream=1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 864, in run
  File "compose\cli\log_printer.py", line 233, in watch_events
  File "compose\container.py", line 215, in attach_log_stream
  File "compose\container.py", line 307, in attach
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
  File "site-packages\docker\api\container.py", line 57, in attach
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 385, in _read_from_socket
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 296, in _get_raw_response_socket
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 248, in _raise_for_status
  File "site-packages\docker\errors.py", line 19, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
  File "site-packages\requests\models.py", line 880, in json
  File "site-packages\requests\models.py", line 828, in content
  File "site-packages\requests\models.py", line 750, in generate
  File "site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 494, in stream
  File "site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 442, in read
  File "http\client.py", line 449, in read
  File "http\client.py", line 493, in readinto
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 209, in readinto
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 20, in wrapped
RuntimeError: Can not reuse socket after connection was closed.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see logs from service use `docker-compose logs service_name`, where *service_name* is key provided in services in docker-compose.yaml
There are useful options like `-f` or `--tail`, more in [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/)

Comment: When first I got this error, I thought that was related to docker. Turns out when I read the logs with the command provided above the problem was about different line ending. The command was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error and as @otong mentions in the comments, looking into the log using `docker-compose --log-level DEBUG` it was actually an issue in a shell script;

`/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory`

The problem was that I'm checking out files from git using the option to checkout with **windows line endings** e.g. `\r\n`. However, the `docker` container is obviously runs linux, at which point the shell script wont run correctly.

Solution is to temporarily check out files with the linux endings ([see details on how to change options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings)).

Or for a quick fix - open the scripts in Notepad++ and replace all `\r` with a blank.

Answer (score -2):

It is also possible because of Windows OS. Try some solutions discussed but if those things don't workout give it a try on Ubuntu.