# How to fix Shebang warning in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When I execute any rails command in my project, I'm receiving this warning:

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems
```

I tried to install another Ruby version, but the warning is the same.
I'm using the same Ubuntu version of the developer.

Comment: _"line ending with \r"_ – seems like your code has Windows line endings, i.e. `\r\n`. Use Unix line endings instead, i.e. `\n`.

Comment: @Stefan I’d say it’s rather Macintosh legacy. Win lines do indeed _end with `\n`_, despite there is `\r` before it.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: The warning is badly worded. The shebang line is terminated with `\n`. If there is a Windows line ending, then the last character that is *part of the shebang line*, i.e. the last character *before the terminating `\n`* will be `\r`. This will still be interpreted as part of the interpreter name by at least some operating systems, so it will actually search for an interpreter executable named `ruby\r`, which it obviously won't find. So, the warning message considers the last character before the terminator as the "line ending" and the terminator not part of the line.

Comment: The corresponding method [`warn_cr_in_shebang`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_0/ruby.c#L1871-L1876) actually checks for `\r\n`. I've opened a [PR](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/2073) to reword the message.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem when I was trying to run `bin/rails db:create`. It took me hours trying to figure out the problem and yet it was an easy fix. I am using Visual Studio Code as my editor.

**My solution**
To solve this, I navigated to the `ruby` file located in the `bin` folder(`bin/rails`). At the bottom of the Visual Studio Code editor(status bar), you should be able to see a button `CRLF`(control character). Click on it and change it to `LF`.

**Reason for the error message**
This is because Windows by default uses the `CRLF` control character and now that you are using a Windows subsystem for Linux, the control character should be `LF`

I hope this helps anyone out there.

Comment: Very helpful since many answers try to use git to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Windows line ending in your file (`'\r\n'`) instead of a unix line ending (`'\n'`). So the shell tries to get the first line, up to and excluding the first `\n`, and finds that the line ends with `\r`.

There are several ways to avoid this issues:

1. With git, automatically: `git config --global core.autocrlf true` (see https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/ and [How to change line-ending settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings))
2. With os-level tools: `dos2unix` (use your OS tools to install it)
3. Editors + editorconfig file: Check https://editorconfig.org/#file-format-details to see how you can set the `end_of_line` config, and let your editor do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Windows:

- Remove git default line ending conversion for Windows: `git config --global core.autocrlf false`
- Convert all files line endings from crlf to lf (I used linux terminal for this):
  `sudo find . -type f  -exec dos2unix {} \;`
- Renormalize with git: `git add --renormalize`

You shouldn't have anything to commit and you can check it worked with:
`git ls-files --eol`