# ruby on rails "warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems" still occurs after tried to fixed it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, foreman

I have cloned one of the repository that apply chatwoot github https://github.com/chatwoot/chatwoot, then I encountered with this warning when execute "rails s" on windows wsl (ubuntu):

```
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/bin/ruby: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems
```

So, I found that changes git config (follow the first solution from this post) will automatically handle this problem, but after I tried with that, it's still display the same as above.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54288670/18770801

The command I tried:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

The server doesn't throw any error (just display warning) but I'm not sure if there is a way to get rid of that message?

==============================================================

Finally, I ran into the problem when I follow the project setup guide `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`

https://www.chatwoot.com/docs/contributing-guide/project-setup

```
17:13:40 backend.1  | started with pid 8482
17:13:40 frontend.1 | started with pid 8483
17:13:40 worker.1   | started with pid 8484
17:13:41 backend.1  | /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
17:13:41 backend.1  | exited with code 127
17:13:41 system     | sending SIGTERM to all processes
17:13:41 frontend.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
17:13:41 worker.1   | terminated by SIGTERM
```

I guess that it probably comes from the same issue but I don't know how to solve that. If anyone can figure it out, please help.

Comment: *I found that changes git config (follow the first solution from this post) will automatically handle this problem* - this isn't true. How did you find it? Setting `core.autocrlf` to `true` can *affect* this, but it can't *fix* this.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't solve the problem, maybe I have misunderstanding at first. I've tried to figure out the problem with several tried and it works for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question:

I've tried to solve this with trial and error several times since I cannot find any answer can solve my problem at all.

In my case, I cloned the repository on Windows system (every files are on my device are located in 'C' drive). That's cause End-of-line format problem when running on wsl (ubuntu). The problem occurs when I tried to run script `foreman start -f Procfile.dev` for booting up my server. Then it throws an error that it cannot find ‘ruby\r’.

This problem comes from the instruction line in `Procfile.dev` which uses `bin/rails` and `bin/webpack-dev-server` files.

To solve this, open project with vs code. Under `bin/rails` and `bin/webpack-dev-server` files, click on `CRLF` format in the bottom right of your screen and change it to `LF` format. This will convert "CRLF" Windows' end-of-line format ("\r\n") into "LF" Linux's format ("\n"). Save both files and restart the server by execute `foreman start -f Procfile.dev` again, and the problem will be solved.