# Unable to prepare context: path ".\r" not found

Tags: linux, shell

I have created `build_docker.sh` file in windows machine which has below contents.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#This script build docker image
docker build -t hello-world .
```

Where I try to run above file using command `sudo sh build_docker.sh` 
It fails with an error, `Unable to prepare context: path ".\r" not found`
I am using `4.2.46(2)-release` Bash version
 
What I am missing here?

Comment: `\r` is a common escape for a literal carriage return. Check for DOS newlines.

Comment: BTW, this is the very first thing in "before asking about problematic code" in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Comment: I tried to edit this file to remove `\r` still facing same issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (LF) in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/608639)

Comment: Tried to edit it *how*? If you opened it in vim, run `:set fileformat=unix` before saving. An editor that things you *want* your file to be saved in DOS format instead of UNIX format will just create CRLFs again when it saves your changes.

Comment: using buldin `vi` editor

Comment: okay, i'll try that command

Comment: BTW, if your script has a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang, you should use `sudo bash`, not `sudo sh`, to run it (or even better, fix its permissions and just run `sudo ./yourscript`). `bash` and `sh` are two different shells, and much code that runs in bash doesn't work in sh.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have specified bash version

Comment: Your `sh` is not `bash`, so the bash version you're using interactively doesn't make any difference whatsoever. Anyhow, that's not part of the problem but is a general aside re: practice issues that'll bite you later.

Comment: OKay, Got it, I'll try with Bash

Comment: That won't fix the problem, which is still caused by CRLFs. But if you changed your script in the future to use bash-only features, it would fail when you start it with `sh`.

Comment: yes, it shows same error with bash as well

Comment: I'll try `:set fileformat=unix`

Comment: It is recommended use `.sh` for files in the POSIX sh language and `.bash` for bash shell scripts.

Comment: I think this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821931/1375110 gives correct solution if using git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

… using `:set fileformat=unix`  and `sudo bash build_docker.sh` solved my problem
                    – Mayur

Answer (score 3):

There is an utility to convert file to unix EOL, it helped me.

```
dos2unix build_docker.sh
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me. had to install this tool using command,
sudo apt install dos2unix

Answer (score 2):

changing file name from filename.sh to .bash solved my issue.

Comment: Good to know that!

Answer (score 1):

This will also work.

```
1. Open all files using vim *
2. Press "qq" to start recording
3. :set ff=unix
4. :wn
5. Press again "q" to stop recording
6. :wq!
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting!