# How to get linux-based code instead of windows-based code in postman code snippets

Tags: postman, code-snippets

I have Windows and loaded the Windows version of Postman, but I want code snippets that don’t contain the Windows-based code in the snippet (Linux instead). Is there a setting I can change or something else I can do to fix this? For example, for Python Request snippet, the following, I believe, is due to Windows (/r/n):

payload = “{\r\n"id”: 2967, \r\n"name": …

I've tried looking at the settings in the applicatin.

payload = “{\r\n"id”: 2967, \r\n"name": …

I'm getting Windows-based code, but want only Linux-based code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with Postman, your best best is going to be to copy and paste the code then search and replace those characters for Unix based ones.

Comment: Would this be a possible solution?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings#answer-10419350