# git wants to change LF to CRLF on windows - how do I fix this?

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf/20653073#20653073), I found the following chart:

> **How `autocrlf` works**:
>
> ```
> core.autocrlf=true:      core.autocrlf=input:     core.autocrlf=false:
>
>         repo                     repo                     repo
>       ^      V                 ^      V                 ^      V
>      /        \               /        \               /        \
> crlf->lf    lf->crl      crlf->lf       \             /          \      
>    /            \           /            \           /            \
> ```

I do most of the development and unit testing locally on a windows box, but the main git repository is on a unix machine, and the code is used on multiple unix machines.

I don't really care how the line endings appear in my windows, but I want very much to **not** have any CRLF in the repository.

I'm using PyCharm, if that makes any difference.

Here's my git settings:

```
# ~/.gitconfig :
[user]
    name = ***
    email = ***
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    eol = lf
```

and

```
# <path-to-my-project>/.git/config :
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    autocrlf = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git+ssh://***
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I'd think I have the correct setup, and yet I get the `warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in`

My current workaround is to `sftp` the files to a unix box and commit/push my changes from there, which is really annoying.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change line-ending settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings)

Answer (score 2):

**1.Set core.autocrlf to false:**
Before you modify the line endings, run the following command to disable automatic line ending conversion:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

**2.Run Line Ending Conversion:**
After disabling automatic line ending conversion, Run the following command to change the line endings of all tracked files in your repository from CRLF to LF:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

For above step, Backup Your Changes and ensure that you don't have any uncommitted changes that you want to keep before proceeding,.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a gitattributes file and specify `* text=auto`. Git will then look at files, guess whether they are text or binary, and perform automatic line ending conversion for you (provided the file was committed with LF endings originally). You can do this by creating a `.gitattributes` file with those contents in the repository or writing a custom one in `.git/info/attributes`. See the [gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for more details.

Once you've done that, you can then set `core.eol` in your config (but not `core.autocrlf`) to whatever you want to use. If you set it to `crlf` or `native` (the default), Git will check files out in CRLF, and since they're text, it will write them with LF into the repository. If you specify `lf`, then you'll get LF always, even in the working tree.

The alternative is to specify `core.autocrlf` (and not `core.eol`) to true, which is equivalent to setting your gitattributes to contain `* text=auto` and `core.eol` to `crlf`.

Answer (score 0):

.... or you could ask git to not mess with eol at all and let you handle it. In `.gitattributes`:

```
*    -text
```

That will do.