# Docker: standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: image, docker, containers, radix

I am trying to create a base image following the instructions given in official docker webpage(https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/scratch/)

```
    docker --version
    Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77

    OS Details:
    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

DockerFile:

```
    FROM scratch
    COPY hello /
    CMD ["/hello"]
```

hello.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
           // printf() displays the string inside quotation
           printf("Hello, World!");
           return 0;
        }
```

I am able to compile the C program and execute locally

I am able to build the image using the dockerfile but when I try to run the container, I get the below error:

```
    # docker run -i hello
        standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" 
    #
```

I expect the container to run successfully and print "Hello World" on console.
most of the answers provided are asking to change EOL which is not applicable as we are already on Linux and not trying to run script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you get this error because you built out a dynamic linked binary like next:

```
$ gcc -o hello hello.c
$ ldd hello
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe3b1ec000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7fe1fc7000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7fe25ba000)
```

The `scratch` is really basic which do not have so many `so` for your binary to dynamic link. So, you need to build out a static link binary, like:

```
$ gcc -o hello -static hello.c
$ ldd hello
    not a dynamic executable
```

Then, it will be work like next:

```
$ docker build -t hello .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  848.4kB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
 --->
Step 2/3 : COPY hello /
 ---> 9d594b34f774
Step 3/3 : CMD ["/hello"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2f1bad3099d3
Successfully built 2f1bad3099d3
Successfully tagged hello:latest
$ docker run -i hello
Hello, World!
```

And, if you do not use `scratch` image which have more `.so` in the system, then you no need to build out static binary.

Comment: In fact, I not quite understand why you insist to use `scratch`, there are so many things not in it, e.g. `sh`, `bash`, if you insist, you can have a look for [this](https://github.com/tianon/docker-bash/blob/fba9ecf51cac8e334263a377fe0c5c0e4de74265/5.0/Dockerfile), it tell you how to install a bash in a image which not have bash. Still, I suggest you to use `alpine`, `ubuntu` or others as base image.

Comment: it worked just fine, thanks! now I'm trying to run a simple .sh script with echo "hello world!" got same error, please suggest.
i tried

`#!/usr/local/sbin/sh
echo "test:" | tee test.txt`

and

````#!/bin/sh
echo "test:" | tee test.txt````

got same error

````standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"````

Comment: `scratch` not have `sh`, not have `bash`, it will be pain for you if you really want that, you have to install all things you needed one by one...

Comment: just trying to learn and try diff things, wasn't aware that bash/sh is not there in scratch, thanks for being prompt!

Comment: There is _nothing_ in `scratch`.  Not even a `/bin` or `/lib` directory.

Comment: Yes, the key is that using statically linked executable. You build environment may be different from the packaged environment. Even with, say alpine, you may see the error.

Answer (score -1):

It seems this happens when the scripts have wrong line feeds. Based on git settings you might have DOS CRLF instead of UNIX LF. Setting the line feeds helped me fix the issue.

[How to change line-ending settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings)

Comment: This question is trying to run a compiled program, not a script.