# Preserving Carriage Return / Line Feeds in GIT repository when cloning or pulling

Tags: git, azure-devops, libgit2, libgit2sharp, azure-git-deployment

Noticed something strange.... I'm using libgit2sharp to clone a repository. The clone command is pretty straightforward

```
LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(sCorrectRepo, sExePath, oOpt)
```

The repository contains, amongst other things, a bunch of .sql files. On most machines these are perfectly fine, but on an occasional client machine I find that all \r\n - "carriage return line feed" line endings have been replaced by just line feeds \n

What could be happening here and, most importantly, is there something I can do to prevent it? In most of the SQL it doesn't matter *that* much but we have a few SQL statements that contain actual text including CRLFs and when **those** are changed to just LFs the text we're trying to use is no longer correct.

Now I'm not very familiar with git so I don't know what I'm doing. My guess would be that I would need to look at gitattributes and adding a line such as

```
*.sql binary
```

but how do I do this in an existing repository? I tried adding a gitattributes file to the .git folder on my windows machine but when I then try to commit (using tortoisegit) it doesn't see any changes.

My remote git repository is on azure-devops

Comment: I suspect I need to do something with the "configuration" of git.... any pointer in the right direction would be welcome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change line-ending settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings)

Comment: Yes ... ish , but I had great "fun" figuring out why it wasn't working on my repository. I'll add an answer below later to show you what I did and what I had to take into account

Comment: Please ignore the answers to that question.  That might have been the state of the art in 2012 but please please use a .gitattributes instead.  https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/advent_day_1_gitattributes_for_text_files.html

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thanks for that. I used a .gitattributes and added *.sql binary and it works. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the solution to this problem consisted of two parts. Firstly, as colinD already suggested in his comment I had to go and change the configuration. Which I did. But it still didn't work for me. The reason was that the last time I committed and pushed my .sql files it had already replaced all line endings with LF in the remote repository. So I removed all the SQL files, commmitted and pushed the removal, re-added them, committed and pushed the re-added sql files, and **then** it worked.

As suggested by @EdwardThomson in his comment I then reverted back to the default settings and I added a .gitignore file instead. In the .gitignore file - at the same level as the .git folder in Windows - I added

```
*.sql binary
```

Did the same exercise again, removing, commit/push then re-adding, commit/push and confirmed that this also works. As suggested this may be a more up to date and appropriate way to handle these.