# How can prevent "\r\n" diffrent on linux and windows os?

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, git

I have a project that create once on linux
at now I work on it on windows os and I have a command to minify assets file; my problem is "\r\n"
in output create new line add cause to different files with previous version, for example if we have :

```
});console.log("test");
```

command output is :

```
});
console.log("test");
```

Can you help me?

Comment: have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git

Comment: Use binary mode on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your IDE should be able to set the line separator. At least Atom, IntelliJ, notepad++ and others support this feature.
2. git itself has a feature to fix/change line feeds. See [git-scm on autocrlf](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_formatting_and_whitespace) and [this SO question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings).