# How to disable certain pre-commit hooks around specific lines of a file?

Tags: gitignore, pre-commit.com

Inside [gitignore/Global/macOS.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/macOS.gitignore), there are two `\r\r` as shown in the below screenshot:

[image: Lines 6 - 11 of macOS.gitignore]

I use `pre-commit==v4.0.1` with its `mixed-line-ending` and `trailing-whitespace` hooks.  Both get triggered on this line.

How can I locally disable those hooks within my `.gitignore` file?

My current solution I employ is `exclude: .gitignore` within my `.pre-commit-config.yaml` for both hooks.  However, I don't like this, as it ignores the entire `.gitignore` file for these hooks, when I really just want to locally disable those two hooks around lines 6 - 8 of the `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no such option for what you want

the `pre-commit` framework **operates on files** so your best bet is to leverage `exclude`:

```yaml
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
        exclude: ^\.gitignore$
```

or more realistically, just remove the `Icon\r` line since it's very unlikely to be hit (only appearing when you customize the icon for a folder on macos). another option is to use `Icon?` instead -- it's slightly less precise but you're probably fairly unlikely to match something else with it

---

disclaimer: I created `pre-commit` and `pre-commit-hooks`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to avoid configuring anything in `pre-commit.com` settings, and make sure the `.gitignore` is checked out with `\n` only in the first place.

For that, try and [add in a `.gitattributes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68298752/6309), in the same folder as your `.gitignore`:

```
*.gitignore eol=lf
```

Comment: that breaks the `Icon\r\r\n` rule on clone / checkout since it converts the `\r\n` to `\n`

Comment: @AnthonySottile Yes, that is the idea, to allow the other pre-commit hooks to not be tripped by those rules.

Comment: the `Icon\r\r\n` is intentional, to avoid checking in `Icon\r` files created by macos when you customize the icon of a directory

Comment: @AnthonySottile OK. I suspect that is a workaround that will need to be revisited, as it has unintentional side effect with other pre-commit hooks.