# Adding local files to git repo throws infinite error warning

Tags: git, eol, end-of-line

When I am trying to add my local code to newly created git repo below error is thrown.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o3VC.png

*warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/objectDestructuringEmpty.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/wrapRegExp.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/writeOnlyError.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/LICENSE', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/README.md', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/package.json', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches itwarning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/path.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/package.json', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3/regenerator/index.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime/README.md', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'node_modules/@babel/runtime/core-js.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it*

I have tried below steps still not working
npm install --save-exact @babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.55
Then delete the package-json.lock file and node_modules folder then re-install with npm install.

Comment: Those message are __not__ errors.

Comment: It may help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.