# Have mercy on me! Install a tool from GitHub

Tags: github

I'm a simple nurse with no technical background. I work in a cath lab. We are the people you go to when you have a heart attack and dont want to die :). Anyways, my colleagues could really use some good, comprehensive education. We often hire people who are new to the profession and need a good foundation. I have taken it upon myself to develop and deliver that education. I want to make sure every patient that comes through our door gets the best, most informed care possible. I work for a for-profit hospital, otherwise known as greedy and cheap. With that being said, I am not being compensated to provide this education and the hospital will not pay for tools to provide it either.

Now that we have that established, education is best served in an interactive format. I have found a wonderful tool here https://github.com/ClaperCo/Claper

I have tried to Google my way through getting it installed and running via the directions on the page. I think I almost have it, but when I get to the last part - ./start.sh - it just wont work.
It says:

cat: .env: No such file or directory
': not a valid identifiert: `
./start.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found

I have no idea what that means!

If someone can walk me through the installation process I would really appreciate. Please talk to me like I am the simplest person you have ever met. Seriously.

I installed all the prerequisites listed on the page and followed the instuctions in a YouTube video to clone the repository and run it in the Git Bash command prompt that was also recommended from the internet. Things were going well until I got to that second to final instruction and was informed by my computer that 'chmod' was not a recognized command (I have Windows 10). After a few hours of research, I found that this is a command used in Linux and that was why it was not working. So, after more research, I ended up installing Cygwin which further confused me and, frankly, created more problems. So I looked for alternatives. I installed Ubuntu for Windows via instructions I found online. That was a colossal headache for me, but long story short I am now running WSL 2. I also tried the Docker methods listed on the page. I was actually successful-ish with that. I ran it and went to the localhost:4000 from my browser like the instructions said and it loaded. I was even able to set up a user name and password. I was satisfied and felt accomplished, so I went to bed (it was 2 in the morning and I had been working on it since 10am!). I woke up and went to play with it and the damn thing wont connect now. It just says 'Unable to connect'. I'm devestated.

Comment: You probably have the file cloned using DOS line endings, which is not compatible with running a Linux script. You can change the setting and re-clone the repository, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings (probably easiest) or use dos2unix to convert the line endings. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117623/how-to-install-dos2unix-on-a-ubuntu-app-on-a-windows-10-machine

Comment: Time to recognize it as a dead-end and go with a different altogether software solution. Knowing when to shift gears is an important part of "tech" work.

Comment: I've looked at this project and at the current time (early 2024) it's a development project, not aimed at the end user. It has no 'releases' or installable outputs.
It seems to be part of a SAAS type product, where the source code is free, but the hosted service is not.  Take a look at [https://claper.co/](https://claper.co/) where you can try the app out, it's hosted for you (I expect at a cost, longer term)
Unless you are willing to get involved in development then the github repository is not really intended at end-users, but still worth exploring for the curious, like yourself.

Comment: Your question, by the way, does not conform to the guidelines for posting on SE. Questions have to be to-the-point and concise, ideally with examples of what you have tried, found out, works and fails. If you explore here (Stack Overflow, intended at developers) and other [Stack Exchange member sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) you will find questions and answers covering a vast array of topics.  See the [SE help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help)