How to restore all files with only line ending differences in a git repo?
I'm working on Windows with core.autocrlf being true. A third party code generator generates files with LF line endings. Every time code is regenerated, git status shows that a large amount of files have changed, but most of them are only line ending changes (CRLF changes to LF). How to restore all those files with only line ending differences? Or, what should the config be so that git will ignore those line ending changes?
This question is different from How to change line-ending settings because that question is about how to change the settings, this question is about how to change the local files, or what should that settings value be.

please check this articale which should answer your issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings?rq=2

if you know what files are generated by this generator: the simplest way would be to replace LF with CRLF in these files (using sed or ...)

Git for windows comes with both unix2dos and dos2unix which are tools for converting between CRLF and LF. In your case, wrap your 3rd party code generating tool in a wrapper script that calls unix2dos ...whaterver_file_name... afterwords.
