# Cannot get git autocrlf=true to work

Tags: windows, git, newline, core.autocrlf

Ok, so i have read all threads on this topic, and my understanding is the following:

if i set core.autocrlf = true in Windows, git should convert all my crlf line endings to LF when committing and pushing.

This is what i want, and i have my config set up as such. However, when i check in a text file with CRLF endings, i get the error messsage:

```
fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF
```

I don't get it... shoudn't the opposite happen when i commit?

Answer (score 4):

The message is misleading, but makes sense:

1. You check in your file, line ending normalization is done: `CRLF` is replaced with `LF`, `LF` is kept as `LF`.
2. Later on, you check out the file in question. Now git will “undo” the line ending normalization: `LF` will be replaced with `CRLF`.

At the end of that process, all the `LF`s in your working dir have been replaced with `CRLF`. That is what git is warning you about.

*Note*: I would not recommend using `core.autocrlf` – it is an old setting that has been superseded. Use attributes instead. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154031/758345