# How to normalize line endings to LF in Git for Windows

Tags: git

I am using [Git for Windows 1.9.5](http://git-scm.com/download/win); my remote repository has mixed line endings (some CRLF some LF). I would like to normalize the remote repository to entirely LF.

My settings:

```
git config core.eol lf
git config core.autocrlf false
.gitattributes * text=auto
```

I have tried:

[Refreshing a respoitory after changing line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings)

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
git status
```

The [gitattributes documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end-of-line_conversion)

```
rm .git/index     # Remove the index to force git to
git reset         # re-scan the working directory
git status        # Show files that will be normalized
```

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154031/57185)

```
git rm --cached -rf .
git diff --cached --name-only -z | xargs -n 50 -0 git add -f
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rm
git checkout .
git status
```

After the `git status`, I open a sampling of files in a text editor and expect them to have changed from CRLF to LF line endings, but none have.

What do I need to do to change all line endings in both my local and the remote repository to LF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set CRLF on the remote repository. Are you sure? Would anybody else object?

After committing your changes have you pushed them to the remote?

in your `.gitattributes` you need to set

```
eol=crlf 
text=auto
```

when you do your `git status` you should notice that you have lots of "changed" files. If you commit these then, that should be the eel's changed.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. No, I have not yet committed or pushed any changes, because I do not yet have any satisfactory changes to make. That is the purpose of this question - to determine how to make the change to commit.

Comment: @Makato eh it is an answer. He needs to push the changes.

Comment: You hadn't added that last sentence by the time I read it, and it doesn't seem like you're entirely confident in your solution.  I'll give you that it's now somewhat "an answer".

Comment: It is not entirely clear what exactly you're suggesting I put in the `.gitattributes` file. Can you show the exact syntax you intend?

Comment: I've made the change you suggested and `git status` does show many files changed, but they all still have CRLF line endings.

Comment: I see the problem. If I `git add .` I get `warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in src/foo.c.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.` The files are the same locally, but will have the desired LF endings in the repository.

Comment: Looks like Makoto owes me an apology :)