# Vb 6.0 project loading error

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I have recently downloaded vb6.o project file from bitbucket but unable to run project it generates following error in log files
'0' could not be loaded
Line 0: The file E:\cas\Forms\errorform.frm could not be loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen this when the line endings for the vb6 files are converted from cr\lf to just lf.

For me this was caused by checking the source code out from git with [autocrlf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings) configured wrong.

Once I had git configured correctly, I needed to execute the following to reset all the line endings in my working copy:

```
git rm -rf --cached .
git reset --hard HEAD
```

**Warning** The above commands will delete all of your working copy files and recheck them out.

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33424884/57913)

Comment: I had the same issue , I converted the line endings manually using notepad++ and it worked

Comment: Sure enough.  git defaults conflicted with vb6.  I can't believe I have to make a vb6 legacy system change.  I too used notepad++ to do a search/replace.  Click on Search > Replace (or Ctrl + H)
Find what: \r\n.
Replace with: \n.
Search Mode: select Extended.
Replace All.

Answer (score 5):

Try open the file with notepad++ and go to the menu View > Show Symbol > Show End of Line.
If you saw the file content is not windows standard (CRLF), then go to the menu Edit > EOL Conversion > Windows (CR LF).

Comment: Thanks you so much, you solved my problem !

Answer (score 3):

The error means VB6 can't find one of the source files. 
 E:\cas\Forms\errorform.frm

Maybe the vbp file has a full path for the form rather than just the filename? Check the vbp in a text editor like Notepad.

Do you have a file errorform.frm from bitbucket? Maybe the file is missing from the archive.

Comment: yes i have errorform.frm but it ask a questions- continue loading project ? in all forms while loading project.

Comment: having errorform.frm is not enough. In the project file (*.vbp file), the file may not be referenced, sometimes it may be referencing to different location. So open project file in notepad and see the path given for this form. correct it to proper path and you can load the project.