# Can I commit specific files in git without affecting the original line ending?

Tags: git

As the question states, we have some test CSV files that need to retain their line endings. These files are used later for testing a CSV parser.

*Non-duplicate edit*: I do not want to convert all files' ending to LF. I want to push specific files to Git end retain their original line ending, e.g. CRLF. So all other files would be normalized to LF which is Git's default while the CSV files will be committed with CRLF.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Git doesn't modify files.

Comment: Git can modify the type of line endings used, both when adding the file to the repository and when checking a copy out into the working directory.

Comment: @isherwood it's exactly as chepner said, have a look at https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#global-settings-for-line-endings

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force git to use LF instead of CR+LF under windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @chepner advice for the .gitattribute file I used him proposed configuration. It didn't work as expected so I did some more digging. Turns out the answer was in the Git manual! (RTFM, I know right?!).

Check the EFFECTS section on [Git Manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

> **eol**
>   This attribute sets a specific line-ending style to be used in the
>   working directory. It enables end-of-line normalization without any
>   content checks, effectively setting the text attribute.
>
> **Set to string value "`crlf`"**
>   This setting forces Git to normalize line
>   endings for this file on checkin and convert them to CRLF when the
>   file is checked out.
>
> **Set to string value "`lf`"**
>   This setting forces Git to normalize line
>   endings to LF on checkin and prevents conversion to CRLF when the file
>   is checked out.

What I actually needed is `-text`. By using `-text` you ask Git to treat that file as a binary and not affect its line endings.

> Unsetting the `text` attribute on a path tells Git not to attempt any
>   end-of-line conversion upon checkin or checkout.

And the backwards compatible version:

> **Backwards compatibility with `crlf` attribute**
>   For backwards compatibility, the `crlf` attribute is interpreted as follows:

```
 crlf        text  
-crlf       -text  
 crlf=input  eol=lf
```

Answer (score 1):

In `.gitattributes`, set the line-ending style to use for the specific files.

```
with-dos-line-endings.csv eol=crlf
with-unix-line-endings.csv eol=lf
```

Comment: Thanks, @chepner. I'll have a look. Does the .gitattributes file goes into the same folder as the CSVs, e.g. src/text/resources/.gitattributes?

Comment: It can. See `man gitattributes` for a full explanation of how and where to specify attribute, but Git will can use `.gitattributes` either in the same folder, or any parent folder up to the repository root.

Comment: ok, so it behaves similar to .gitignore. I'll keep you posted, thanks.