# git autocrlf set as input not working as expected

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

I have set my global git configuration using this line

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

From what I read, I understand that upon commit line endings should be converted to LF no matter if my repository is on windows or unix.

when I commit, however, the CRLF is kept as is.
To verify I reset the file after committing it.

Comment: Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows

Comment: I don't think so, I want to be able to change the line endings to LF upon commit