# Git says I am adding '^M' but core.autocrlf is true

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

The problem is simple enough. Git is saying I've added CR (`^M`) to a file,

```
me@myComp MINGW64 /c/workspace/service (develop)
$ git diff --check
engine/src/main/java/someFile.java:18: trailing whitespace.
+import some.java.package;^M
```

but I have `core.autocrlf` set to true.

```
me@myComp MINGW64 /c/workspace/service (develop)
$ git config --get core.autocrlf
true
```

I've not run into this problem before and not sure what's causing it. I've always had `core.autocrlf` set to true and it's never complained about adding `^M` before now.

---

Here is the output of `git config --list` with some personal info, gui settings, and branch settings removed just in case it's needed.

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
push.default=simple
core.autocrlf=true
core.pager=less -x4
core.trustctime=false
core.editor=vim
core.filemode=false
alias.hist=log --pretty=format:'%ad %C(yellow)%h%C(reset) %s %C(yellow)%an%C(reset)' --date=short
alias.logo=log --oneline
alias.superlog=log --decorate --graph
alias.superlogo=log --decorate --graph --oneline
alias.dry-merge=merge --no-commit --no-ff
gui.recentrepo=C:/sts-workspace/kba-service
merge.tool=vimdiff
merge.conflictstyle=diff3
mergetool.prompt=true
mergetool.keeptemporaries=false
mergetool.keepbackups=false
mergetool.trustexitcode=false
diff.tool=vimdiff
difftool.prompt=true
color.ui=true
credential.helper=cache --timeout=3600
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
```

Comment: How did you checked out the file? from which OS?

Comment: @codeWizard I am on Windows using Git-for-Windows. I checked it out by `git checkout develop`.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the repo after the config change ? https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings

Comment: @Rabee I didn't *change* the config, it's *always* been that, just to clarify. I did try that series of commands though and at the end I got that the working directory was clean with nothing to commit.

Answer (score 0):

As for the reason why it's suddenly decided to do that there's 2 possibilities.

1. Either there's something specific in the repo's attributes file that's changed
2. There's something in there with a line that has a windows style line ending so it's decided to default to that style.

Config for windows can be a bitch and is way more hassle then linux / mac, but it's not unmanageable.

I'll just show you my own config (win 7 / mingwin) and you should be able to search what i've done pretty easily. I specifically spent about half a day researching this initially because im kinda OCD just so i could be sure the line endings were always converted to unix based (LF) on commit.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig
[core]
    autocrlf = false
```

---

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitattributes

* text=auto
```

Note you should probably look up how to config the default git attributes which can also be set on a per project basis if needs be. I use the web one out of these  [useful templates](https://github.com/Danimoth/gitattributes) but your own needs may vary.

---

```
C:\Users\BAXTER\.gitconfig

[core]
    eol = lf
```

P.S. This is probably a duplication to some extent of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows)

Comment: Oh and also you'll have to do a commit if you want to re index all the line endings (see chronials answer on the duplicate).