# Git: Why am I getting a warning LF will be replaced by CRLF when text=lf

Tags: git, line-endings

I know there are many questions "LF will be replaced by CRL" but I believe my question is unique as I'm attempting to force LF line-endings, even on Windows, so don't want autocrlf=true.

To force the LF I created a .gitattributes in the root of my repostory with a line:

```
 * text=lf
```

However, when I attempt to add a file now I get the "LF will be replaced by CRLF" warning.   Why would it replace with CRLF given my .gitattributes?  I believe my global git settings have autocrlf=true, but I thought my .gitattributes would override that.

Another proposed Answer only address .txt files (*.txt), I needed all files determined to be text by git to use LF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force git to use LF instead of CR+LF under windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh!   .gitattributes line should have been

```
* eol=lf
```

The warnings can be suppressed using:

```
git config --global core.safecrlf false
```