# amended line ending with Vagrant & ZSH

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vagrant, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a vagrant box where I change the default Ubuntu shell to `oh-my-zsh`.
I have a shared folder containing a `.zshrc` that I copy to the vagrant home folder during provisioning.  At some point the line ending for one line in the `.zshrc` has `^M` appended to it so I get the following error when I `vagrant ssh`:

`/home/vagrant/.zshrc:source:4: no such file or directory: /home/vagrant/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh^M`

The `^M` is not visible in the `.zshrc` file. If I use vim in the vagrant box and re-write the `.zshrc` file then everything works as expected.

How can I ensure my `.zshrc` won't have this line ending character appended during the process of `git clone`-ing the repo and `vagrant up`-ing the box?

I'm using Vagrant in Windows 7.

Comment: look this one for git config http://stackoverflow.com/a/37261875/4296747

Comment: ah, yes adding the lines `git config --global core.autocrlf false` & `git config --global core.eol lf` to my windows machine fixed it, thankyou! If you put as an answer I'll accept it. :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows/13154031#13154031) you can make the following setting in git

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git config --global core.eol lf
```

and you will have no issues when cloning the project