# What extension is a target at Git's autocrlf

Tags: git

I am in charge of system engineer at Japanese company.
We are programmed POS by VB6 and our source managed by Git.

Currently we notice ".bas", ".frm" extensions are not targeted autocrlf.
We checked ".gitignore", "gitignore_global". But we did not set these extensions.

**I want to know the reason why extensions was not changed.**

Comment: It seems that git did not recognize files with ,bas and .frm extension as a text file.

Comment: Add a `.gitattributes` file and specify those files are text files.

Comment: you mean when you check the `git status` it doesn't show `.bas` or `.frm` files got change ?

Comment: You can refer to https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes on how to tell git handle a file as text file.

Comment: so sorry. i mean that currently our autocrlf status is true. so if we commit and push to git, the sources will change crlf to lf. but ".bas", ".frm" files did not change. if we need to automatically change, we must add ".gitattributes" ?

Answer (score 0):

> but ".bas", ".frm" files did not change

That might be because of an *existing* [`.gitattributes` which would instruct the file eol style differently](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#gitattributes-Settostringvalueauto).

```
*.bas       text eol=lf
*.frm       text eol=lf
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
We did also check .gitattributes which is existing or not. But the file is nothing... Do you know anything file which is relation to change crlf to lf?

Comment: @Takeru if there is no .gitattributes, then you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154031/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/33424884/6309

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation. I will follow and continue to search this problem.