# Why Git Bash vs msys2 git throw different git status?

Tags: bash, git, msys2

Assume I have a git folder in `/d/projects/project01`.

When I do `git status` in Git Bash, and `git status` in msys2, it throws different output (image below)
Why this happen and you could I make those 2 work identically?

[image: git bash status vs msys64 conflict]

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` outputs in each directory?

Comment: I believe git in MSYS2 sometimes gets confused about files that had changes to their line endings.  You can try making a commit, and you'll probably find that those changes just disappear.  You can also read about git options like `autocrlf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the output of `git config core.autocrlf` in both session.

If it is false in git bash, but not in mingw2, set it to false in the second mingw2 session:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Comment: `core.autocrlf` should be considered deprecated.  This repository - and all repositories - need `.gitattributes`.  https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/advent_day_1_gitattributes_for_text_files.html

Comment: @EdwardThomson Yes, I have said that for years on Stack Overflow. (like 2010: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2517442/6309)

Comment: I know!  That’s why I was so surprised to read your answer!  :D

Comment: @EdwardThomson My answer is simply to start and make sure `core.autocrlf` is set to false in both environment. Then we can move on to `.gitattributes`

Comment: it return `true` in Git Bash and nothing in msys2 (seem it's impicit that in msys2 core.autorlf = false)

Comment: @Luke Can you type `git config --global core.autocrlf false` in both sessions, then clone again your repository, and see if the issue persists?

Comment: @vonc it works identically now, thanks very much.