# Is there a way for Eclipse to run Java unit tests in the same way a unix (TeamCity) build host can? org.junit.ComparisonFailure issue

Tags: java, eclipse, unix, junit, teamcity

I have a bit of a weird issue where I can build our code base without any issues via TeamCity. On the other hand when I trigger the build via Eclipse I get org.junit.ComparisonFailure.

Code that is failing is as follows:

```
@Test
public void prettyPrintTest() throws BunchOfExceptions {
    InputStream formattedXml = DomUtilsTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/sample/file/formattedOutput.xml");
    InputStream notFormattedXml = DomUtilsTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/sample/file/notFormattedInput.xml");

    DocumentBuilder builder = ClassBeingTested.getDocumentBuilderFactory().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document notFormattedDocument = builder.parse(notFormattedXml);
    String prettyPrintedXmlContent = ClassBeingTested.prettyPrint(notFormattedDocument);
    
    Assert.assertEquals(IOUtils.toString(formattedXml), prettyPrintedXmlContent);
}
```

The unit test is fine on TeamCity, and it is fine on my colleague's IntelliJ (he wrote this code). But I get the following error on my machine:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
expected:<<message>[
    <header>
        <messagetype>HelloWorld</messagetype>
    </header>
    <body>
        <messageBody>HolaComoEstas!</messageBody>
    </body>
</message>
]
> but was:<<message>[
    <header>
        <messagetype>HelloWorld</messagetype>
    </header>
    <body>
        <messageBody>HolaComoEstas!</messageBody>
    </body>
</message>
]
```

Any idea how I could configure Eclipse to run this in the same way that a TeamCity Unix host does it? Or is there a way to make this unit test platform independent?

Comment: Are you on Windows, and are you using Git? Your problem is likely one of line-endings (`\n` on Linux, `\r\n` on Windows). You may need to normalize it, or use a diff/comparison library that is able to ignore such differences.

Comment: Probably encoding problem. What if you manually compare the two strings?

Comment: Also consider comparing XML properly instead of as strings.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen it has to be compared as strings because the pretty print function is used in a logger as a string. When I manually compare the strings they look identical.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel, I ran dos2unix to account for line-endings and that fixed my issue. See answer I submitted.

Comment: If you're using git, you can also configure it to not change the lineendings, see [How do I force git to use LF instead of CR+LF under windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by opening git bash, going to the path of the formatted XML file (E.g. C:/path/to/sample/file/formattedOutput.xml) then executing dos2unix as:

```
dos2unix.exe ./formattedOutput.xml
```

So it looks like [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) was correct in the comment above.

Thanks