# I can't open an existing Git repo file as LF on Windows. No matter what I do

Tags: windows, git

I have a Git repository on Github using LF as line-endings.

When I'm on Windows, I can't, for the life of me, to make existing files to show using LF endings.

What I have tried so far:

- I ran this globally `git config --global core.autocrlf false`
- I cloned my repo again.
- I tried normalising my repo with `git add --renormalize .`
- My repository has a `.gitattributes` file with `* text=auto`.
- On WebStorm, I set `Editor -> Code Style -> Line separator: Unix and macOS (\n)` <- Apparently this only affects new files.

Now, if I open any existing file on WebStorm or VSCode, the file still shows as `CRLF`. As in the Screenshot.

How can I make it, so that, when I open an existing file, it will show as `LF`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I executed this ritual [How do I force Git to use LF instead of CR+LF under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows). I have no idea what I'm doing:

- `git config core.eol lf` <-- I'm not sure if this one is necessary or even right.
- `git rm --cached -rf .`
- `git diff --cached --name-only -z | xargs -n 50 -0 git add -f`
- `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 rm`
- `git checkout .`

The only "problem" is that, on VSCode, new files are still in CRLF (disgrace). So you need to edit your `settings.json` file (Ctrl+,) and add this:

```
{
  "files.eol": "\n"
}
```