# Nodejs saving file linebreak dosent work on initial run

Tags: node.js, line-breaks

I am trying to generate a list of links inside `<fileName.txt>` file like this:

```
fs.writeFile(fileName, linksRemaining, function(err){
```

But if the file already exists I want to continue adding links without over-writing old ones. So I simply check if it exists store the data in a variable and add the additional content after a line break. like this:

```
fs.exists(doneFileName, function(exists) {
 if (exists) {
     fs.readFile(doneFileName, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if(!err){
            linksCurrentDoneList = data;
            linksCurrentDoneList = linksCurrentDoneList+'\n'+linkTarget;
            callback(1);
        }else{
            return console.log("Error: "+err);
        }
    });
    ....
```

The above code is in a loop and puts links several time, Issues is that on first run of my loop it negates line break `'\n'` but on 2nd and so on loops it works...

Suppose I am running loop for three links at a time, the result will be like this in notepad:

```
http://www.link1.com/
http://www.link2.com/
http://www.link3.com/http://www.link4.com/
http://www.link5.com/
http://www.link6.com/http://www.link7.com/
http://www.link8.com/
http://www.link9.com/http://www.link10.com/
http://www.link11.com/
.....
```

What I am trying to achieve is quite obvious... a line break for each link -- I am completely out of clue why is this happening,

In frustration I tried the following:

```
linksCurrentDoneList = '\n'+linksCurrentDoneList+'\n'+linkTarget+'\n';
```

But didn't help, in fact the line break was still just 1(same as the example above). Any one have any clue what might be going on?

### **EDIT:**

Every link is on a separate line if I open my `.txt` file in another software like ms-world !!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to use append function to append data to a file.

```
var fs =require('fs');

fs.appendFile('test.txt', "This is a test.\n",  {flag: 'a'}, function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('The data was appended to file!');
});
```

Note that if test.txt doesn't exist, appendFile() will create.  Here is he output running 2 times:

```
This is a test.
This is a test.
```

Comment: Thanks Ben i didn't knew there was a function for that :)

Comment: btw what what does 3 parameter `{flag: 'a'}` does?

Comment: Your answers did optimized my code but it didn't solved the actually problem... how ever **[THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755029/windows-notepad-not-supporting-newline-character-n)** did .. i think you should add it here as well.

Comment: Imran, for the explanation of {flag: 'a'}, 'a' means 'append" which is default for fs.appendFile(), so you don't actually have to specify.  However, you can pass in as {flag: 'ax'} to tell fs.appendFile() that it should return as error instead of creating the file.  For the line separator.  Sorry I didn't know that was the problem.  Thanks for pointing it out. Actually, the better approach to solving the platform dependent line-separator would be to use nodeJS's OS module (var os = require('os')). Use os.EOL instead of '\n' or '\r\n'.  That way your code will be portable with all platforms.

Comment: One more comment, if you can append the urls into a buffer first (with a loop) and do 1 fileAppend() operation, then that would be better than having fs.fileAppend() in the loop since file IO is expensive.

Comment: I was just wondering if '\r\n' will cuz any other problems but thanks to you i will use OS Module.

Comment: yes it would & that what i did in the first place but i am scraping 1000 of links and it takes too much time so i though 1 link at a time will save the memory then storing data from 1000 of links etc...