# Newline in output from Unix not appearing in Notepad

Tags: unix, sas, newline

Ok, Im new to SAS and have been working on a fixed formatted output .txt file. Each Variable needs to be starting at a particular column and be a fixed length and format. I have been using a PUT statement to accomplish this. So far so good.

Where I run into an issue is when I open the output.txt in notepad, the first line follows the rules defined in the put statement until it is time to move down to the next line. data continues to write on the first record opposed to creating a new record at the end of the put statement.

This only occurs when I open the file in a windows environment (notepad). When I view it in UNIX editor everything is the way I need it.

```
    data _null_;
    set work.get_driver_data;
    file ".......................dw2092340/driverdata.txt" LRECL = 269;
    DV_Term1 = compress(put (DV_Term, mmddyyn8.),'.');

   put @001 SCAC $4. 
   @005 DV_REF $10. 
   @15 DSP_OFFICE $13. 
   @28 UP_RMP $5.
   @33 DV_HIRE mmddyyn8. 
   @41 DV_TERM1 $8. @49 FIRSTNAME $20. 
   @69 MID $10. @79 LASTNAME $20.
   @99 LICENSE $20. 
   @119 LIC_STATE $2. 
   @121 LIC_CNTRY $3. 
   @124 LIC_EXPIRE mmddyyn8.
   @132 LIC_CDL $1.
   @257 BNSF_PIN $10.;
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: In addition to RawFocus's answer, this depends on how you transfer the file from Unix to Windows.  If you transfer it via FTP, and do so in Text format, usually the FTP program will convert it for you.  If you're writing to a network drive or similar, then it won't.

Comment: Note: starting May 2018, [Notepad finally will support \n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50241693/6309)!

Answer (score 2):

What is your goal?   It sounds to me like you are creating a text file with UNIX style line endings.

If you want this to open in Notepad, you need to give it windows style line endings.  Try this on the end of your file statement:

```
termstr=crlf
```

This stands for "Carriage Return Line Feed".  Alternative values include:

LF   (Line Feed) - use `TERMSTR=LF` to write files suitable for unix systems.

CR   (Carriage Return) - use `TERMSTR=CR` for mac systems (not a common use case).

If you are only trying to look at your results, perhaps you should consider using a fully featured text editor - there are many free ones available that will open files in all of these formats.  I use Notepad++ but there are many others.

Also, check out the documentation for the filename statement under [unix](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#chfnoptfmain.htm) and [windows](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#chfoptfmain.htm).

Comment: Good answer.  You might want to explain the difference in line terminations in a little more detail, since odds are the user may not be familiar with what this does.

Comment: a good suggestion..  In our (cross platform) systems, we always use unix line endings.  These can be easily read by windows, whereas the other way round (windows format in unix) is not so reliable.