# "\n" not working with Buffered writer in NotePad?

Tags: java, newline, notepad, bufferedwriter

I am writing a Java Program(using Eclipse IDE) with swing to convert MIPS code from  octal to Binary notation ,

the issue is no matter what i try i can't seen to get the output file written line by line, i tried many thing don't know whats going wrong , please help me

In the input file i  have say

F A B 4
F F F F

the output appears as

1111 1010 1011 100 1111 1111 1111 1111

but when i open in NotePad++ etc the formatting is fine , please help me

I want it to look formatted when i open in notepad also 
like this

```
1111 1010 1011 100 
1111 1111 1111 1111
```

I guess its something to do with text Editors and not the program, anyways here is the method that does the work ...

public void convertFile()

{
    try{

```
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));


JFileChooser fileSave=new JFileChooser(".");//open chooser with current working directory
fileSave.showSaveDialog(frame);

outputFile=fileSave.getSelectedFile();

BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

String line="";
String binaryVal="";
String binaryLine="";
String[] token;

//read from input file and convert and save in output file
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
{
    token=line.split("\\s+");
    binaryVal="";
    binaryLine="";

    for(int i=0;i<token.length;i++)
    {
        binaryVal=HexToBinaryConverter.hexToBin(token[i]);
        //System.out.println(binaryVal);
        binaryLine=(binaryLine+binaryVal+" ");
        //System.out.println(binaryLine);
    }//all tokens in a line have been processed ,now write to file
    System.out.println(binaryLine);

    writer.write(binaryLine+"\n");

}

    //entire file has been processed now close everthing
writer.close();
reader.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Some exception in FIle IO");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "Invalid Hex Numbers.",
            "Inane warning",
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

}

Comment: \r\n for windows, Notepad++ is smarter than Notepad.

Comment: In Windows it is `\r\n` as it uses CRLF

Comment: Ok ,it wont affect the actual formatting(meaning or valueof data) right? , as in if i need to process the output again in another program , is it just the appearance ?,then i have no issue, will /r/n work for ubuntu ?, which is safe , please explain , this is the first tme i'm encountering all these problems. Thanks!

Comment: Note: starting May 2018, [Notepad finally will support \n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50241693/6309)!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use PrintWriter. It is a little more efficient than appending a `\n` and it will use the platform specific carriage return.

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filename)) {
   // do something
   pw.println(binaryLine);
   // something else.
} // close when done.
```

`println` will use `\r\n` on Windows and `\n` on Linux/MacOSX.

> i question is will using \r\n render my jar program or executable unrunnable in UNIX?

Your program will run except you will get a `^M` which is `\r` at the end of every line of text you write.

Answer (score 1):

Java is meant to be cross platform. Use the standard library properly and you won't have headaches like this.

Check out: [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator())

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses CRLF (carriage return - line feed) as a line end, which is notated as `\r\n`. Unices (and other POSIX-complaint OS-es) use only the line fee character: `\n`.

If your application have or could have anything to do Windows, it is useally recommendable to use `\r\n` all the time.

Or of course, there are tools (classes) that hide these OS specific nuances.

Comment: I'm sorry , i question is will using \r\n render my jar  program or executable unrunnable in UNIX?

Comment: No, Unices ignore the carriage return.