# Writing multiple lines to notepad file python

Tags: python, newline

I am trying to write to a notepad file with binary encodings each separated by a newline.The gist of the code is as follows

```
with open("filedir","ab") as Afile:
    Afile.write(info+"\n")
```

However, the outputs are just being appended and not new lined.

Comment: Note: starting May 2018, [Notepad finally will support \n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50241693/6309)!

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing to a binary file (like you say) and you want it to work properly on Windows (I'm assuming you're on Windows since you're talking about notepad), then you need to use the Windows line endings `"\r\n"`. Given that you're trying to write line endings in the proper "encoding" I'd have to ask why you want to use binary mode, given that all it does is disable converting "\n" into "\r\n" on Windows.

Comment: Indeed, it should be `open("filedir", "at")` on Windows (and MSDOS).