# php ctype_alpha not working for mysql db data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to filter out results from a list of bike models which contain numbers, e.g: "BAJAJ CT 100 ALLOY". I'm using str_replace to remove spaces before using ctype_alpha() to check the results for numbers. it doesn't seem to work. I'm totally lost.
Here is my php code:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM vehicleList WHERE 1;";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
    $bikeListArr = array();
    $carListArr = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if($row["type"] == "bike") {
            // echo str_replace(' ','',$row["model"]) . "\n";
            if(ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ','',$row["model"]))) {
                array_push($bikeListArr,$row["id"],$row["model"],$row["category"]);
            }
            else echo $row["model"] . " -- DROPPED\n";
        } else {
            array_push($carListArr,$row["id"],$row["model"],$row["category"]);
        }
    }
    // print_r($bikeListArr);
}
```

And here is part of the output:

```
HERO HF DAWN KICKSTART -- DROPPED
HERO HF DELUXE -- DROPPED
HONDA DREAM NEO -- DROPPED
BAJAJ PLATINA -- DROPPED
HERO SPLENDOUR -- DROPPED
```

Interestingly below values passed:

```
"TVS STAR CITY PLUS","HERO PASSION X PRO","HERO GLAMOUR","HERO HUNK"
```

Cant find what's wrong. I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: is your select statement correct and why you added semi colon at the end of it?

Comment: Why not use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) as in `preg_match('/\d/', $row['model'], $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)`?

Comment: @ Amr Aly: Yes, it is. I've always used ";" at the end. Most probably it is copied from a previous working snippet of mine. :-)

Comment: @tadman: could you please explain the line? especially the "PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE" part.

Comment: why not do it in the query instead, something to the effect of using a regex `WHERE col REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'`? or `REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'`

Comment: @fred: I can't as I need the actual values in jQuery ui autocomplete. That's another long story, for another question maybe. I think Something seems to be the problem in this snippet. It's results are weird

Comment: Are spaces in the values dropped really spaces? Output also the str_replace output to see if the characters which look like spaces are really gone.

Comment: @Norbert: I've tried that already. The line is commented out in the given snippet above.

Comment: @atf I linked to the documentation which explains in greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the reason for the problem. The database table was populated by a PHP script that reads lines from a .TXT file in Windows OS and fed the "model" column of the "vehiclelist" table.

Guess what? Notepad in Windows OS needs both `\r` and `\n` to represent a linebreak. (Source: [Windows notepad not supporting newline character '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755029/windows-notepad-not-supporting-newline-character-n)). PHP recognized only the `\n` character as a linebreak, so the `\r` character was left at the end of most lines (Still haven't found why all lines didn't have it..). a simple update with [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on all lines of the table did the job, and the code works fine now. Hurray!!

Code Snippet to update table:

```
$db=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","mdb") or die("DB Timeout... Please try again");
$query="SELECT * FROM vehiclelist WHERE 1;";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $query1="UPDATE vehiclelist SET model=\"" . trim($row["model"]) . "\" WHERE id=\"" . $row["id"] . "\";";
    $result1=mysqli_query($db,$query1);
}
```

A simple `var_dump()` of the `$bikeListArr` array showed the anomaly in the sizes of the strings corresponding to the "model" values.

It really was a wastage of everyone's time. I'm sorry I could not see that before.

Thanks to all for all their answers and time.