# line breaker not working after exporting .txt file to sFTP server

Tags: java, tomcat, sftp

I am exporting .txt file to sFTP server, when I am downloading file from sFTP server all text printed in single line means line breaker is not working, even I exported file to local folder line breaker was working perfect but from sFTP line breaker is not working.

Used **System.lineSeparator() and \r\n, \r and also more examples but still file is customizing**

**I want file should be like below:**

```
               test|test|test|test       
               test|test|test|test    
               test|test|test|test
```

**But it looks as below after download:**

test|test|test|test                   test|test|test|test                   test|test|test|test                   test|test|test|test                   test|test|test|test

**I am using Tomcat server and Java 8 in Linux environment.**

Comment: maybe your text editor is not showing you correct format. As I know for example sometimes notepad not showing end lines correct but notepad++ works well

Comment: Thank you very much, It was blocking me from last few days but from your point its working thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. I will make it as an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

you should try with :

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

if it doesn't work its the "\" that might be the problem here you could try to double it

the first one to say that the second isn't a computer tag

Answer (score 1):

There are line-breaks, however different operating systems recognise different sequences for line-breaks.

Notepad only recognises CR, LF (0x0d, 0x0a), whereas other sources might use CR only, or LF only.

You can't make Notepad behave differently, so your only option is to make sure the content has the right sequence for Notepad. Note that notepad is the only editor with this restriction, so if your content works in Notepad, it will work everywhere else.

One simple way to fix the line-feeds is to copy and paste the text into Word, then back again into notepad, and the line-feeds will get "corrected" to the CR,LF sequence.

Also you can use other text editors like notepad++, sublime, etc. For more information visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755029/windows-notepad-not-supporting-newline-character-n/50241693#50241693)

Answer (score 0):

FTP is notorious in that a Windows line ending `\r\n` can be converted to a Unix line ending `\n` when the file in not transferred as **binary** data (as opposed to **text**).

On Windows a text file with `\n` will *not* be seen as line separator in simple text editors like Notepad.

Use an other editor like Notepad++ or JEdit.

So

- On FTP use binary transfer
- Use a programmer's editor

There also is a simple bug where lines are read, and text is composed of those lines, forgetting the dropped new lines:

```
StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(...);
for (;;) {
    String line = in.readLine(); // No line ending!
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    fileContent.append(line); // Forgotten: `.append("\r\n")`
 }
 return fileContent.toString();
```

So

- Check the reading code