# Are there any differences between plain text files exported from Google Docs and plain text files written in Notepad?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-docs, notepad

I'm writing an application that is able to import data from a plain text file line-by-line in Kotlin so long as the first line contains a certain string, and through trying to make it work I've run into an issue: the text files I generate through the application or type in Notepad will import fine so long as they meet the criteria set in my code, but an identical text file exported from Google Docs will not.

Here's an example. Say I write up a file in Notepad called *locationstoimport.txt* in Notepad containing the following:

```
STRING_TO_MATCH
ADDRESS_1
ADDRESS_2
ADDRESS_3
ADDRESS_4
ADDRESS_5
```

When I try to import this into my application, I have no issues. The string in the first line, in this case `STRING_TO_MATCH`, is accepted by the application, and so the five addresses listed are imported.

Now, say I either (A) copy and paste the text from locationstoimport.txt into a Google Doc or (B) open locationstoimport.txt in Google Docs on my phone, then export it as a new text file called *googledocslocationstoimport.txt*, which contains the following:

```
STRING_TO_MATCH
ADDRESS_1
ADDRESS_2
ADDRESS_3
ADDRESS_4
ADDRESS_5
```

When I try to import this into my application, the application rejects it, saying the first line does not match. In theory it should since the data contained in both files is exactly the same and both files are plain text files, but my application doesn't seem to think so.

Is there some difference between plain text files written in Notepad, generated by Android applications, and exported by Google Docs that I should be aware of? Worth noting: when I export the first file to Google Docs and save it again as a .txt file, it's 5 bytes larger than the original. I don't know if that is affecting what is going on, or if it should be.

Thanks!

Comment: It may be a problem with `\r\n`, `\r` and `\n`

Comment: Could you extrapolate on this a bit, if you have the time/desire to do so?

Comment: Either the EoL setting as @user says, or perhaps ASCII vs UTF-8 vs UTF-16 or some other encoding.  You probably need to look at it byte by byte, or else use Notepad++ to tell you.  ETA, Notepad can add a BOM to the start of UTF-8 files where it isn't needed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755029/windows-notepad-not-supporting-newline-character-n

Comment: What @rossum is probably what's going on here, not the newlines. I was talking about how different platforms encode newlines in different ways. With Windows, it's `\r\n`, and I'm not sure how Google Docs does it

Comment: Be sure to trim your lines and check encoding

Comment: Thank you all so much! I never considered that this could cause so much of a problem with importing something into an application. I wish I could give all of your comments gold star best answers >:)