# Git checkout remote branch creates locally modified files

Tags: git, version-control

I'm working on the trunk of a project locally and need to checkout a remote branch.  My working copy is fully up-to-date, and i run

```
git checkout -b RC1 origin/RC1
```

After that I run

```
git status
```

And it tells me I have about 30 files that are modified and untagged.  I open a visual interface to view the changes in the files and they are 100% the same.  When I run

```
git diff
```

I get:

> The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
>   warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in src/private/library/arialunicid0-chinese->traditional.php.

My question is why are all of these files considered to be modified?  Shouldn't my branch be clean, with no changes if I just checked it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the [`git checkout` manpage](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout),

> **`git checkout <branch>`**
>   Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that they can be committed to the <branch>.

So no, the working copy will not always be clean after a checkout; your files were probably modified before the checkout, or your autocrlf settings are messing stuff up for you. It's generally less of a headache to turn off EOL-conversion in Git and instead make sure that all developers use editors which can handle all EOLs -- and agreeing on one kind of line ending (e.g. unix-style, LF only).

Comment: Ahh it was the EOL-conversion by git that was the issue.  I went ahead and implemented [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933004/best-way-to-disable-git-end-of-line-normalization-crlf-to-lf-across-all-clones) and it worked.  Thanks for the help!