# Unix-style line endings on Windows servers

Tags: windows, git, unix

I started a new job and we use Windows servers for PHP (local, dev, stage, live), but the new project was committed with Git for Windows with the default setting "use Unix-style line endings for commits" (paraphrasing) selected by the team members, and now any file I open with Notepad shows files with no newlines.

I can use other file editors to read the files (though it's more steps for quick views), but I'm worried that the Unix-style line endings will cause issues with Windows servers. I haven't seen a problem yet with the new or old code (the latter of which had mixed files), and committing with CRLF shows up in the git diff, so it could look bad unless all files are converted at the same time with an obvious message.

Is it going to be worth converting to CRLF? I doubt the system will move to Unix (they're entrenched pretty heavily and use IBM System i infrastructure as their data backbone), but I'm not sure Unix-style line endings will cause a problem.

Comment: It might help to know the languages involved (Java and related IDEs, as well as web content are tolerant of line-endings, C/C++ depend upon particular tools).

Answer (score 0):

Use [gvim](http://www.vim.org/download.php) for windows, or any [number](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) of [other](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/) [text](http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/staff/steveb/cpaap/pfe/) [editors](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) that work with unix newlines.

Comment: The question isn't about which editor to use on my Windows box, it's about committing Unix-style line endings and compatibility with Windows servers.

Comment: His issue was opening up the file in notepad.  Windows servers don't (generally) care about line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Windows *servers* work fine with Unix line-endings.  The problem would be if you are planning to use the files on the Windows servers (other than editing and compiling).

There is one area in which Windows expects CRLF files: the `".bat"` files.  Simple batch-files work with LF-endings, but if the script is long enough (more than a few thousand characters) and uses internal subroutines you can have a non-working script (this has been noted by others, e.g., in this [bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7478)).

Likewise, checking Unix shell-scripts in with CRLF-endings tends to break them if one attempts to use them as-is on Unix (see *[Bash/Korn shell script edited on Windows throws error '…^M: not found'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56024/bash-korn-shell-script-edited-on-windows-throws-error-m-not-found)* for example).

If you have a cross-platform system with scripts for Unix and Windows, you likely will need to separate those into different folders/directories in Git and use [attributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) to specify CRLF or LF-endings according to their use.   The *[Best way to disable Git end-of-line normalization (CRLF to LF) across all clones/machines? (core.autocrlf vs…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933004/best-way-to-disable-git-end-of-line-normalization-crlf-to-lf-across-all-clones)* question is a starting point; however it is simplistic:  Git attributes can be managed per-directory (though it can be tedious).  In particular, it is easier to apply these selectively to ".bat" files (using wildcards) than to shell scripts (which need not use *any* naming convention).  So -- with the caveat that some filetypes must be handled specially -- using Unix line-endings makes the system easier to manage.

There are, as noted, other editors than Notepad (but StackOverflow is not the place to list these).

Comment: In your first paragraph you say Windows servers work fine with Unix line endings but the problem would be if we are using the files on Windows servers other than editing and compiling... well, yes we're coding files to be run on Windows servers (PHP specifically), so I'm not sure what you mean by "use".

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd categorize PHP files as "web content": it seems that most of the file types which can be served/processed on a web interface have made allowances for line-endings.  On the other hand, it is not uncommon for other types (such as C and Unix shell) to run into problems with line-endings, particularly when dealing with continuation-lines).